# GD32V Input pin not being pulled down, but acts like a floating pin

Tags: c++, embedded, riscv

I am using a GD32VF103CB chip on the longan nano board.
I am trying to read a pin(Pin B15) from this board with the following code:

```
RCU_APB2EN |= 0x1 << 3; 
GPIO_OCTL(GPIOB) &= ~(0x1 << 15);
GPIO_OCTL(GPIOB) |= (0x0 << 15);

GPIO_CTL1(GPIOB) &= ~(0b1111 << 28);
GPIO_CTL1(GPIOB) |= (0b1000 << 28);
               
GPIO_BOP(GPIOB) &= 0x0;
bool x = (GPIO_ISTAT(GPIOB) & ( 0b1 << 15));
```

I am using the official device header files, with the values from the [user manual](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwih5JKc6vfsAhWoxoUKHWN4DngQFjAAegQIChAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdl.sipeed.com%2FLONGAN%2FNano%2FDOC%2FGD32VF103_User_Manual_EN_V1.0.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1oPWySmJrU4ro7Q6SB0erx).
This *should* config pin B15 as an input pin, with pull-down. I then read the status of the pin with the ISTAT register and store it in 'x'.
I then write 'x' to the led pin.

However, the pin then acts as a floating pin. Basically the LED pin is always on, no matter what if I connect it to 3.3v or nothing. However if I connect it to ground, it goes out.

Therefore I tried different pin configurations, like push up and floating, but they all had the same effect. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
As clarification: I am trying to write the status of the pin(pin B15) to the built in LED on my longan nano board. I am using the function below for this.
Please note that here, port is 0 and pin is 1.(This means port A, pin 1 which is the built in blue LED).

```
     // Enable the peripheral clock on the rcu
            RCU_APB2EN &= ~(0x1 << (port+2));
            RCU_APB2EN |= 0x1 << (port+2);

            // Set the OCTL for the pin to 1(output high)
            GPIO_OCTL(GPIOA) &= ~(0x1 << pin);
            GPIO_OCTL(GPIOA) |= (0x1 << pin);

            // Set the pin as out push_pull with a speed of 50mhz(ctl0 or 1 based on the pin number)
            if(pin<8){
                GPIO_CTL0(GPIOA) &= ~(0b1111 << (pin*4));
                GPIO_CTL0(GPIOA) |= (0b0011 << (pin*4));
            }else{
                GPIO_CTL1(GPIOA) &= ~(0b1111 << ((pin-8)*4));
                GPIO_CTL1(GPIOA) |= (0b0011 << ((pin-8)*4));
            }

        GPIO_BOP(0x40010800U + (0x00000400U*port)) &= ~(0x1 << pin);
        GPIO_BOP(0x40010800U + (0x00000400U*port)) |= (0x1 << pin);
```

Comment: Your problem has to parts: reading the input pin and driving the LED. Please focus on the LED first and provide more information: Show the code that is supposed to turn the LED on and off. Explain better how you LED is connected (schematic is preferred). And what exactly are you trying to achieve? Should the LED (on or off) reflect the state of the input pin (high or low)?

Comment: @Codo I edited my question to include this more clearly. Yes I am trying to turn the led on when the input pin is HIGH and when the pin is low, it should turn off. I want the input pin to be pulled down(so that it's low when nothing is connected). The led is builtin on the longan nano board

Answer (score 1):

You are never clearing the bit.

```
Port bit operate register (GPIOx_BOP, x=A..E)
15:0    BOPyPortSet bit y(y=0..15)
These bits are set and cleared by software
0: No action on the corresponding OCTLy bit
1: Set the corresponding OCTLy bit to 1
```

You need to use `GPIOx_BC` to clear a bit.

```
Port bit clear register (GPIOx_BC, x=A..E)
15:0    CRyPort Clear bit y(y=0..15)
These bits are set and cleared by software
0: No action on the corresponding OCTLy bit
1: Clear the corresponding OCTLy bit to 0
```

Be careful , when you do `RCU_APB2EN &= ~(0x1 << (port+2));` you are Disable GPIO port B clock (when port = 0).

probably your code will probably be like:

```
void init(int pin){
    RCU_APB2EN |= 0x1 << 3; 
    GPIO_OCTL(GPIOB) &= ~(0x1 << 15);
    GPIO_OCTL(GPIOB) |= (0x0 << 15);

    GPIO_CTL1(GPIOB) &= ~(0b1111 << 28);
    GPIO_CTL1(GPIOB) |= (0b1000 << 28);
               
    // Enable the peripheral clock on the rcu
    RCU_APB2EN |= 0x1 << 2;

    // Set the OCTL for the pin to 1(output high)
    GPIO_OCTL(GPIOA) &= ~(0x1 << pin);
    GPIO_OCTL(GPIOA) |= (0x1 << pin);

    // Set the pin as out push_pull with a speed of 50mhz(ctl0 or 1 based on the pin number)
    if(pin<8){
        GPIO_CTL0(GPIOA) &= ~(0b1111 << (pin*4));
        GPIO_CTL0(GPIOA) |= (0b0011 << (pin*4));
    }else{
        GPIO_CTL1(GPIOA) &= ~(0b1111 << ((pin-8)*4));
        GPIO_CTL1(GPIOA) |= (0b0011 << ((pin-8)*4));
    }

}

void pin_to_led(int pin)
{
    bool x = (GPIO_ISTAT(GPIOB) & ( 0b1 << 15));

    if (x){
        GPIO_BC(0x40010800U ) &= ~(0x1 << pin);
        GPIO_BOP(0x40010800U ) |= (0x1 << pin);
    }else{
        GPIO_BOP(0x40010800U ) &= ~(0x1 << pin);
        GPIO_BC(0x40010800U ) |= (0x1 << pin);
    }
        
}
```

I deleted port since you used GPIOA in the code.
the function init will be called once. the pin_to_led function should to be called in a loop  ( while (1)) for test or from an interrupt handler (timer for example).
You will need also to be sure that pin is between 0 and 15.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment! I just tried this, yet unfortunately it did not change the behaviour :(

Comment: how do you set/unset the pin B15?an other board?

Comment: I use a breadboard and connect the pin with jumper wires

Comment: Are you doing the GPIO_STAT  GPIOB_BOP/BC   in a loop?

Comment: yes. otherwise the value of x will not change . it will take the first value you are reading with  GPIO_STAT . or you can use an interruption ...

Comment: okay I’ll try it out either tomorrow or Monday :) thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224539/discussion-between-yflelion-and-vvamp).